# Jenkins SSL configuration - site won't load

Tags: java, ssl, jenkins

I am trying to configure Jenkins to use SSL (ideally without a port number as well, but one step at a time!)

I followed plenty of guides online and generated the various keys and certificates and ultimately a JKS file.

I edited the Jenkins config file to update the following options:

```
JENKINS_PORT="-1"
JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT="8443"
JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE="<path_to_jenkins.jks>"
JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD="<your_keystore_password>"
```

but after restarting Jenkins and checking the service was running, the site would simply not load in the browser.

I did eventually find some info about just adding `--httpsPort=8443` in the `JENKINS_ARGS` option, and reverted the other options, and that actually works somehow. I can access the site via https://jenkins.domain.com:8443

Oddly, if I set the `JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT` option itself, rather than `JENKINS_ARGS` afterwards, again the site fails to load.

I'm reading a lot that the self signed certificate should be used if possible, so I'd like to get this working.

Java info

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_272"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_272-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.272-b10, mixed mode)
```

Jenkins v 2.263.4

Running on AWS EC2 Amazon Linux 2 instance